# Why means are different in Rstudio?

Tags: r

I am using mean function in R. But getting different answers all the time, I change the sequence of the inputs.

Not able to understand. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

```
> mean(10,12,13)
[1] 10
> mean(12,10,13)
[1] 12
> mean(13,10,12)
[1] 13
```

Comment: I am not really sure but I think you should use canonical vectors not supply as x, y, z. These may be taken as the inputs to other args eg trim. Try `mean(c(12,10,13))` and see. and `mean(c(13), trim=12, na.rm=12)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass numbers as a vector to `mean` and not as separate values. See `?mean`.

```
mean(x, ...)
```

So when you are doing `mean(10,12,13)` you are just getting mean of 10 hence the same number is returned. Same with `mean(12,10,13)`.

Pass them as a vector with `c(...)`.

```
mean(c(10,12,13))
#[1] 11.66667

mean(c(12,10,13))
#[1] 11.66667
```

This is different behaviour from functions like `sum`/`min`/`max` where you can pass different numbers as comma separated values.

```
sum(10, 12, 13)
#[1] 35
min(10, 12, 9)
#[1] 9
```